# Redirect stdout to stderr but keep it also in stdout

Tags: bash, stdout

I want to be able to redirect `stdout` to `stderr` but keep the content of `stdout` in there also.
So not exactly redirect but `clone` or `duplicate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically:

```
command | tee /dev/stderr
```

Answer (score 1):

If the sole purpose is to split stdout to terminal and a file, another idea:

```
mycommand | tee -a /tmp/stdout-content
```

**NOTE:** `-a` says to append to the file; to overwrite the file each time `mycommand` is run you can remove the `-a` (which leaves you with the same thing KamilCuk just posted)

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```sh
mycommand | awk '{print; print | "cat 1>&2"}' > /tmp/stdout-content

# and stout is also in stderr (visible in the terminal)
```